# PERL How to convert localtime format to unixtime

Tags: perl, unix-timestamp

Can anyone helpme with this? I have a time value in a the logfilefile which has following format:

**Tue Aug 28 09:50:06 2012**

I need to convert this time value into unixtime.

regards

Comment: Note: A date in that format is ambiguous if the time zone used has daylight saving time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best choice here is [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece), which is a core module and so shouldn't need installing. It has an `strptime` method for parsing time/date strings and an `epoch` method for returning the Unix epoch time

It is convenient to roll this into a subroutine as shown here

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece ();

print date_to_epoch('Tue Aug 28 09:50:06 2012'), "\n";

sub date_to_epoch {
   return Time::Piece->strptime($_[0], '%a %b %d %T %Y')->epoch;
}
```

**output**

```
1346147406
```

Comment: this one is working fine, thanx a lot but I'm still wondering why the solution of Brian doesn't work for me

Comment: Maybe you have an older version of `Time::Piece`? The latest is v1.20 and I think at some point it weas changed to use the platform `strftime` instead of a pure-Perl internal implementation

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (requires [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Format-Strptime-1.52/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm)):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern   => '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y',
  locale    => 'en_US',
  time_zone => 'local',  # Or even something like 'America/New_York'
  on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime('Tue Aug 28 09:50:06 2012');

print $dt->epoch() . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the strptime function in the Time::Piece module to parse the date, then use the strftime function to return the Unix timestamp.

```
use Time::Piece;
$parsed = Time::Piece->strptime("Tue Aug 28 09:50:06 2012", "%a %b %e %T %Y");
$unixtime = $parsed->strftime("%s");
```

Comment: Hi Brian, "$parsed->strftime("%s");" doesnt't deliver anything. Is it maybe because I'm running it on Windows?

Comment: @taiko: `strftime("%s")` works fine on my Windows box, so something else must be wrong. Much better is the `epoch` method, which avoids the overhead of formatting and returns a number instead of a string: see my answer

Comment: hmmmm, thats funny I tried to print other elements of strftime and they are fine, only %s doesn't deliver anything

Comment: @taiko I don't know about Windows, but it works just fine for me on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Ok, no prob, maybe I have some bug on my system. Fortunately the solution of Borodin is working fine. Thanx  alot anyway

Comment: @taiko, You are probably using a Perl distribution which depends on Microsofts C run-time library (ActiveState?). The '%s' conversion specifier is a vendor extension and is not supported by Microsofts implementation of [strftime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: yeah, you got me. I'm uing ActiveState perl